# Properties of $3\times 3$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, affine-geometry

Given two sets of corresponding points $\mathbf{P}_1, \mathbf{P}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$, where $\mathbf{P}_1, \mathbf{P}_2$ are pointclouds expressed as matrices, we can derive a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ such that:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{A} = \arg \min_{\mathbf{A}} \sum_{i=1}^n \| \mathbf{A}\mathbf{P}_{2,i} - \mathbf{P}_{1,i} \|_1
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{P}_{1,i}$ is the $i$-th point of $\mathbf{P}_{1}$ and $\|\cdot\|_1$ is the $1$-norm.

If $\mathbf{P}_1 \mapsto \mathbf{P}_2$ denotes something resembling a non-affine transformation (e.g.: isometric bending), the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ closely approximates such non-affine transformations.

My question is a bit generic: I want to know more about the properties and possible decomposition of such *general* $\mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ matrices, I care most about $d=3$. They are neither affine, nor projective. I could not find a lot of literature about them. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Are you acquainted with the [orthogonal Procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem)?

Comment: It is the same problem with the orthogonal constraint removed

Comment: If you switch to the Euclidean norm, you have a least-squares problem

Comment: Yes, but my question is about the properties of A, not the solution methodology. Given ideal, outlier-free data, I guess the numerical values of A obtained by solving L1 or L2 norm would be pretty similar.

Comment: Maybe, but the $2$-norm has no "corners", which makes it nice and allows for a closed-form solution

Comment: Indeed, please change it if you wish, but the rest of the question still holds.

Comment: I don't see how you could say much about $A$ in general.  For any $d \times d$ matrix $A$ and any point cloud $P_2$, you could choose $P_1$ so $P_{1,i} = A P_{2,i}$ to make $A$ a minimizer (and it's unique if $P_2$ spans $\mathbb R^d$).

Comment: Indeed, so can you not decompose into affine and non-affine matrices? I just want to know what other properties/identities are known/easily-deducible about/from these matrices?

Comment: Just an update, you can chose $A$ to have $P_1 = A P_2$, not just $P_{1,i} = A P_{2,i}$ for some specific $i$ but $\forall i$